# Swizzle a class without an instance of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category, swizzling

I need to swizzle a class that I don't have a reference to at the point I'm trying to swizzle at. I'm using the "indie" swizzling method so that I can swizzle any class from anywhere, but it requires an instance of that class to get the `Class` reference.

So the example code has this line:

```
Class class = [NSURLSession sharedSession].class;
```

However, I need to do something like:

```
Class class = classof(ViewController); //ViewController is a class, not an instance
```

Or something like that. Is this possible in ObjectiveC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the exact same way :

```
Class class = ViewController.class;
```

Comment: Well that seems obvious in retrospect, very difficult thing to search for on google though

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use NSClassFromString method, or am I misundestand something?